# webview with full screen in android

Tags: android, webview

i have made a simple hello web view example and i want to make it in full screen like i do not want that two top most black bars.
anybody have any idea how to do that?

thanks a lot.

Comment: What "two top most black bars"?

Comment: I think he's referring to the title bar and notification bar?

Comment: yes tittle bar and notification bar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The quickest way to do this would be to add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Into your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: when applied to a "phonegap" project, the activity launches in fullscreen and then (after couple of seconds) the title-bar shows up again... any idea?

Comment: never mind, got the answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833995/no-status-bar-in-phone-gap

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can do it programmatically in the OnCreate method of your Activity :

```
//Full screen
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: A better solution is to use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in the `<activity>` element in the manifest.

Comment: You are right, I edited my post to present it as an alternative, should someone need to do it programmatically.