# no status bar in phone gap?

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, css, cordova

I have been trying to get the status bar to go away as i want to put a fullscreen game in.
i'm using phonegap for the iphone

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

1) call this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]
```

2) or this from your view controller.

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

3) You can do it from the Interface Builder. Here's a video about it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPAChohC-4Q

4) Someone else asked the same thing and got some related answers:
[Fullscreen UIView with Status bar and Navigation Bar overlay on the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373791/fullscreen-uiview-with-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-overlay-on-the-top)

Answer (score 33):

For iPhone simply add

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true />
```

in your *[appname]*-info.plist file

For completeness if you also wish to roll out for android this solution worked well

In the file where you change activity to droidgap

```
public class app extends DroidGap
```

Add the following import

```
import android.view.WindowManager;
```

And then append the following within the class method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Hope this helps

regards

Comment: In Xcode, you add item and choose YES as the value, but same thing.

Comment: Setting the key in plist solved it - I'm using cordova 3.x theres a global config.xml that contains a flag for fullscreen - but it didn't hide the statusbar - thaks Drewid

Answer (score 6):

If you want to the app to load with the status bar initially hidden:

- [appname]-info.plist file
- Find "Status bar is initially hidden"

  - Add new row if it isn't already there
- Select 'YES' for the value

"Status bar is initially hidden" is the key that is available at least in xcode 4.2 beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS7, you'll need to set the following setting in your [appname]-info.plist:

'View controller-based status bar appearance' to NO (Boolean)