# How to hide navigation bar on Android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar on phonegap but without success.

I manage to do it in a native application using

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);        
webview.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION); 
setContentView(webview);
```

On phonegap nothing seems to work. I've tried the following without success

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [PHoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833995/no-status-bar-in-phone-gap)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out. It works on a device but not on the emulator.

Thanks

Comment: how did you solve this? using the plugin, which is still not available on phonegap build?